# How to iterate a LinkedList elements in reverse order?

Tags: java, collections, linked-list, iterator, listiterator

I m new to Java Collections and my doubt is why can't i traverse a element in linkedlist in backward directions.Below I'll explain what i did and please clarify my doubts.

1. I've created interface **iterator** for forward iterations and **listiterator** for backward iterations. Why backward iterations are not working ?
2. Can't i use **iterator** and **listiterator** interface in the same program to traverse a set of elements in forward and backward iterations ?

   Code Snippet :

   ```
   import java.util.*;
   class NewClass{
   public static void main(String args[]){
     LinkedList<String> obj = new LinkedList<String>();

      obj.add("vino");
      obj.add("ajith");
      obj.add("praveen");
      obj.add("naveen");

      System.out.println(obj);

      System.out.println("For loop ");
      //using for loop
      for(int count=0; count < obj.size(); count++){
        System.out.println(obj.get(count));
      }
     System.out.println("For each loop ");

     //using foreach loop
     for(String s:obj){
        System.out.println(s);
     }
     System.out.println("Whileloop ");

     //using whileloop
     int count=0;
     while(obj.size() > count){
         System.out.println(obj.get(count));
       count++;
     }
     System.out.println("Forward Iterations ");
     //using iterator 
     Iterator it = obj.iterator();
     while(it.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(it.next());
     }
     ListIterator lit = obj.listIterator();
     System.out.println("Backward Iterations");
      while(lit.hasPrevious()){
       System.out.println(lit.previous());
         }
       }
    }
   ```

   **Output**

   ```
   [vino, ajith, praveen, naveen]
    For loop 
    vino
    ajith
    praveen
    naveen
   For each loop 
    vino
    ajith
    praveen
    naveen
   Whileloop 
    vino
    ajith
    praveen
    naveen
   Forward Iterations 
    vino
    ajith
    praveen
    naveen
    Backward Iterations
   ```

Where is the output for Backward Iterations? Please anyone help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you start iterating from the last list element?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think you want a [`descendingIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#descendingIterator()).

```
Iterator lit = obj.descendingIterator();
System.out.println("Backward Iterations");
while(lit.hasNext()){
  System.out.println(lit.next());
}
```

Comment: This is a compile error (when the code is used as-is).

Comment: `for (int i : (Iterable<Integer>) obj::descendingIterator) { ... }`

Answer (score 7):

You can do it, but you need to use the method `listIterator(int index)` to specify that you want to start at the end of the `List`.

```
LinkedList<String> obj = new LinkedList<String>();

obj.add("vino");
obj.add("ajith");
obj.add("praveen");
obj.add("naveen");

ListIterator<String> it = obj.listIterator(obj.size());
while (it.hasPrevious())
    System.out.println(it.previous());
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting from Java 21, simply using [`LinkedList.reversed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html#reversed()):

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>(List.of("A", "B", "C"));
for (String s : list.reversed()) {
  System.out.println(s);
}
```

**Note:** It returns a reverse-ordered [view](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#view) of this collection.

Additional details in [JEP 431: Sequenced Collections](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431).